# Python ranges (again)

Tags: python-3.x

Basically need a program that sums the squares of numbers in a range. So far I've got

```
n = int(input("Enter the smaller number: "))
o = int(input("Enter the larger number: "))
for i in range(n,o + 1):
  print(i**2)
```

When smaller number 3 is entered and larger number 6, it gives me an output of 
9
16
25
36
rather than 86.

Also, I am having trouble with another program which is meant to multiply negative numbers in a range, eg, if I input -6, it will go -1*-2*-3*-4*-5*-6 giving an output of 720. I have no clue of doing this and haven't been able to find out anywhere.

Comment: Why should it give `86`? You're not adding the squares, you're just printing them out.

Comment: I'm trying to get the sum of them.

Comment: Not in the code you posted you aren't.

Comment: I've tried using the sum to add them but I get a type error 'TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable'

Comment: If you post the code that got that error, we can help you understand why it was wrong.

Comment: I just used the code as in the original post, although instead of print(i**2) I tried print(sum(i**2)) which came with the error

Comment: The argument to `sum()` has to be a list -- it adds up all the elements of the list. `i**2` isn't a list, it's just the square of the current number in the loop.

Comment: I've shown how to do it with `sum()` in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the sum, you have to add the squares to a variable.

```
total = 0
for i in range(n, o+1):
    total += i**2
print total
```

You can do this in one line with `sum` and a list comprehension:

```
print sum([i**2 for i in range(n, o+1)])
```

I don't understand the problem you're having with multiplying negative numbers. `720` is the correct result of that product. When you multiply two negative numbers, you get a positive result, that's grade school arithmetic.

Comment: `sum()` would be more pythonic

Comment: I figured there's a more pythonic way, but I'm not really an experienced Python programmer. This is just a basic loop that works in any language, translated into Python.